# Calculating Minecraft Explosions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a voxel world, similar to Minecraft. Each voxel(block) is the size of 1x1x1.

I want to calculate destruction of explosion at a certain position with a given Radius for explosion, meaning that around that position the game will destroy voxels (given the wanted Radius).

Meaning that I want some sort of function that does that:

```
void DestroyBlocks(Vector3 position, int radius){   
if(block is on radius)   
destroy(blockPosition);
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you store the blocks somewhere (eg. list, array) or have a tag on the blocks?

Comment: You can use Vector3.Distance, to check the distance between the center of a given block and the center of the explosion.

Comment: yes, I have chunks that store the blocks via array. But you can get any block at a given position via env.getVoxel(position);

Comment: @Andreaジーティーオー I see, so I just calculate distance and see if its not bigger than radius?

Comment: first check on a bounding box `if (dx <= radius || dy <= radius) ...` only then check on actual distance with `Vector3.Distance`. To compute the distance, you have to compute the square root `sqrt()` of the deltas and this costs much. But it is for sure farther away if it's outside the bounding box, so checking that first gives you a HUGE speed-up.

Comment: if you are building a voxel world, you should store your voxels in an 3d array like this `GameObject [,,] voxels = new GameObject [100,100,100];` this will be very useful for you in many cases - one case is that you can very easily locate voxel neighbours - and much faster than with physics / collision / distances

Comment: @SpoocyCrep: exactly

Comment: @pid thanks ill try my best to implement it!

Comment: As person who knows little about Unity, I would suggest forming a inequality that describes the sphere of explosion and checking if the blocks' coordinates satisfy the inequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done with the [`Physics.OverlapSphere`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html) function:

```
void DestroyBlocksWithinRadius(Vector3 center, float radius)
{
    Collider[] result = Physics.OverlapSphere(center, radius);
    for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
        Destroy(result[i].gameObject);
}
```

---

If there are no colliders, then do it manually by finding them by tag and checking the distance:

```
void DestroyBlocksWithinRadius(Vector3 center, float radius)
{
    GameObject[] result = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Voxels");
    for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
    {
        Transform tempTrans = result[i].transform;
        float distanceSqr = (center - tempTrans.position).sqrMagnitude;
        if (distanceSqr < radius)
            Destroy(tempTrans.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure it will work if my voxel world is one mesh and one collider. My voxels dont have their own colliders or maybe I don't understand the solution

Comment: See my Edit for no collider solution. If the voxel is in Mesh format then you should read [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/118287/how-can-i-delete-parts-of-a-mesh-in-unity) and also [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/exploding-voxels.285757/) which has code example for exploding Mesh voxels.

Comment: Of course, I'll mention that if each of your voxels is a full `GameObject` you're going to hit memory limits on your visible area *really* fast. Minecraft at a render distance of 10 chunks has (assuming ground level of 64) around 1,982,464 blocks loaded. Minecraft can do this because each one takes up 1 byte of memory. A full game object is *way* more than that.

Comment: @Draco18s *"you're going to hit memory limits on your visible area really fast"* GPU Instancing is now supported and built into Unity and this is where it is needed.

Comment: I was thinking about non-graphics memory concerns, but that's good to know.

Comment: @Draco18s Yes. It also has to do with non-graphics memory concerns. You just need one prefab customized any how you like then use use GPU Instancing to create many of them on the GPU

Comment: Ah, neat. I don't think I'd heard about that yet.